# VB.net Accessing Structure from dll

Tags: vb.net

I wrote the following C code to create and export a structure and a routine used to fill the structure with values.
The routine and structure are both exported from a DLL.

```
__declspec(dllexport) struct x_struct *test_structure; 
__declspec(dllexport) void load_structure(void); 

struct x_struct {
    long x_long;          
    float x_float;          
    char *x_cstar;          
    struct x_struct *test_structure;
    };

void load_structure(void)
 {
    test_structure = (struct x_struct *)CstdlibMalloc(sizeof(struct x_struct));

    test_structure->x_long  = 22;
    test_structure->x_float = 55.0;
    test_structure->x_cstar = CstrCpy("test string");
 }
```

I declared the dll routine like this in the VB module:

```
Declare Sub load_structure Lib "Test.dll" ()
```

I access the routine from VB like this:

```
  Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
      Call load_structure()
   End
```

Sub

That all works fine.  I can step into the C routine and see the structure variables being filled.

What I can't figure out is how to import the structure from the DLL.
Neither Declare or DllImportAttribute will allow me to specify a structure instead of a subroutine or a function.

Comment: I haven't worked on any unmanaged to managed projects before, but I would refer to the Marshalling namespace http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/asx0thw2.aspx

Comment: actually, disregard that.. I meant the system.runtime.intropServices namespace (which the Marshal class) is in; However, you may be more interested in the TypeLibConverter Class http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.typelibconverter.aspx

or, more specifically, programmatically creating InteropAssemblies at runtime.